# How to multiple functions with data file

Tags: python

I've managed to create data extraction and output to file,but how add more events to file?
 have this code:

```
f = open('input.csv', "r")
f2 = open('output.txt', "w+")
lines = f.readlines()
for line in lines:
words = line.split("|")
f2.writelines(words[5]+"|"+"\n")
f.close()
f2.close()
```

(need to check and remove blanks in input file before processing to output, need to check for duplicates before processing to output, need to remove certain matching lines before processing to output)

I have input file:

hello|one|good|bad|weird|man|world|

hello|one|good|bad|weird|man|world|

hi|jungle|12345|present|small|ladie|world|

I need output file:

man|

ladie|

Comment: What are "events"? Show us a sample of the input and of the desired output.

Comment: You code is poorly indented, and you do not show any will to do some work ahead... What have you tried? What advice do you want exactly?

Comment: check the below code, it'll find duplicate contents, blank lines in your 'input.csv' and remove that. What are the matching lines, you want to remove?

Comment: For starters, `f2.writelines("+words[5]+"|"+"\n")` is not a Python expression.

Answer (score 0):

This will remove blank lines and duplicates before writing it to the output file. What kind of matching lines you want to remove?

```
f = open('input.csv', "r")
f2 = open('output.txt', "w+")
lines = f.readlines()
lines = set(lines)
for line in lines:
    if line != '\n' and line != "|||REMOVE ME|||\n":
        f2.writelines(line)
f.close()
f2.close()
```

Comment: thank You. I want to remove line which is exactly "|||REMOVE ME|||" :)

Comment: sorry.but i get error with your code "there is an error in your program wit expected and intended block"

Comment: this provides the result. Check it and let me know if you have any issues

Comment: i've editted question to show input and desired output

Comment: I don't know how to merge your and my code to ged desired results provided in question